# Backup all contents of current directory to a subdirectory inside the current directory, which will be created if not exists

Tags: command-line, file-copy

Right now I have following command to copy all contents of the current directory to sub-directory, provided if the subdirectory is created in advance:

```
cp -p !($PWD/bakfiles2) bakfiles2/
```

But I have to some times visit those folders which I have never visited before, so sub-directory "bakfiles2" may not exist there, can I somehow create that backup directory with current timestamp(as to avoid conflictions with any existing directory), on the fly when with single copy command or bash script ?

It would be great if the script can ignore any sub-directory starting with a particular pattern which could then be reserved for `backup` directory names like `_bak_*` (**Note:** * means any number of any characters).

Comment: I don’t understand; is your question just “How do I create a directory?”

Comment: How do I create sub-directory **inside** my current directory **on the fly** when I am copying the contents of current directory to that sub-directory ?

Comment: How do I eat a chicken sandwich while standing on one foot in an airport? The same way I eat any sandwich, anywhere, standing or sitting down. You seem to know of the concept of a bash script, so I don’t understand what you’re asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cp` command doesn't have an option to create destination directory if doesn't exist while coping, but you can achieve with scripting.

or simply use `rsync` command which can create destination directory if doesn't exist only on last level.

```
rsync -rv --exclude='_bak_*/' /path/in/source/ /path/to/destination
```

- note that leading `/` in `/path/in/source/` will prevent coping source directory itself and adding `--exclude` option to don't sync directories with matched name.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a current timestamp with the `date` command

```
date +'%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'
```

You can copy the contents of a directory only to a directory that already exists, unless you're using a recursive copy. However, you can't use a recursive copy unless you want the previous backup directories also copied to the new backup directory.

So this has to be done in a couple of steps

```
backup_dir="_bak_$(date +'%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')"
mkdir "$backup_dir"
cp -p !(_bak_*) "$backup_dir/"
```

Bear in mind that as written this will not copy dot files (files beginning with a `.` character), since these are usually treated specially by the shell. (You might want to consider naming your backup directory `.bak_*` instead of `_bak_*` to benefit from this feature. You can then `cp -p * "$backup_dir/"`)

There's no reason why this couldn't created as a little function or script, so it's then still only one command.

Comment: Your last command says - `bash: !: event not found`, do I need to add any other lines, or this is just a glitch ?

Comment: @VST you must already have `extglob` enabled because otherwise your own example in your question couldn't have worked.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that, I didn't know maybe someone else has enabled that already in the system.